get pull request id via commit sha
I am working on a pipeline that has a lot of folders with different services on in.
Each time a pull request is done all the services are being re deployed as we do not know which one might have changed.
This task is being done on GH actions
The approaches I've been working on where:

make a diff between two commits
grab all the files from the pr that is being merged

The 2nd approche feels more natural as it seems logic to get a list of what have change in order to work on them.
The list file can easily be pulled via something like:
URL="https://api.github.com/repos/${{ github.repository }}/pulls/${{ github.event.pull_request.number }}/files"
            #URL="https://api.github.com/repos/${{ github.repository }}/pulls/${{ steps.pr.outputs.pull_request_number }}/files"
            FILES=$(curl -s -X GET -H "Authorization: Bearer ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}" $URL | jq -r '.[] | .filename')

I had no luck trying to get the PR linked to the SHA of the PUSH.
Does anyone have a hint on how to do it?

If your services are organized in different folders in your repository, you can leverage GitHub Actions’ paths filter to only trigger deployments for services that have actually changed. This way, only the services in which files were modified will be redeployed.
name: Deploy services
on:
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, synchronize]

jobs:
  service_a:
    if: github.event_name == 'pull_request'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - name: Deploy Service A
        if: ${{ github.event.pull_request.head.ref }}
        run: echo "Deploying Service A"
    paths:
      - 'services/service_a/**'
  
  service_b:
    ... same goes for b


h Thanks for the response, despite it being a valid approach, with this solution you would need to add a new step every time a service is added. What I am trying to determine is what files are modified and extract the folder, what is the name of the service that would be returned to respond.
